# Whenever im starting the service mail is not sending but when i will debug it is sending mail as i expected

Tags: c#, email

Whenever i'm starting the service, it is not doing any operation as service is not "sending mail" but when i will debug it is sending mail as i expected.Why it is happening i do'nt know.I think this is not the problem with the code.as coding as running fine when i'm debugging. Please suggest me.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
namespace MyUtility1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {

        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            OnStart(null);
        }



        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Timer t1;
            t1 = new System.Timers.Timer();
            t1.Enabled = true;

            Task.Run(() =>
                {

                EnvVars envVars = EnvVars.GetSettings();
                });

        }


        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }     
    }  
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

using System.Net.Mail;
using System.ServiceProcess;

using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace MyUtility1
{
  public  class EnvVars
    {

        public static EnvVars GetSettings()
        {    EnvVars envVars = new EnvVars();

            String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"H:\\EDI", "*.brl", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            if (files.Length > 0)
            {
                var mail_server1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mail_server");
                var mail_from_address1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mail_from_address");

                var mail_address1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mail_address");

                MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(mail_from_address1, mail_address1);

                mm.Body = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("body");

                mm.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("subject");

                mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

                int leng = files.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
               {
                  String sep = "   |  ";

                    String Body1 = String.Join(sep, files, 0, leng);
                   mm.Body = Body1;
                }

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mail_server1);
                try
                {
                    client.Send(mm);
                }
                catch (Exception e) { }

            }

           return envVars;
        }

    }
}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
      <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>

    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="dkamd@gmail.com" />

      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="localhost"
                 port="25"
                 defaultCredentials="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <appSettings>

    <add key="mail_server" value="mail.gmail.com"/>
    <add key="mail_address" value="dkamd@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="mail_from_address" value="dkamd@gmail.com"/>
    <add key="body"  value="New file found"/>
    <add key="subject" value="BRL files"/>
    </appSettings>
  </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the permissions.
under what account is the service running? 
Does it have permissions to access the file system?
(Also might be a problem with the mail client, though less likely)

To check this issue, 
add try - catch with logs to your code.

Something like this:

```
 using System;
public  class EnvVars
    {

        public static EnvVars GetSettings()
        {  
            EnvVars envVars = new EnvVars();

        try{
            //TODO - log begin work
        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"H:\\EDI", "*.brl", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        if (files.Length > 0)
        {
            var mail_server1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mail_server");
            var mail_from_address1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mail_from_address");

            var mail_address1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("mail_address");

            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(mail_from_address1, mail_address1);

            mm.Body = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("body");

            mm.Subject = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("subject");

            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

            int leng = files.Length;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
           {
              String sep = "   |  ";

                String Body1 = String.Join(sep, files, 0, leng);
               mm.Body = Body1;
            }

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(mail_server1);

                client.Send(mm);

        }
        }
            catch (Exception e)
        {

                //TODO - log exception
            }


        finally
        {
       return envVars;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: whenever i will remove the login for finding out .brl files and keep the email sending logic then code will work and email will be sent. But when i add brl logic it is not giving any error as wel as any output

Comment: could you please show the corrected code with try-catch and logs?

Comment: im not getting where to add try catch in my code and what is logs

Comment: i have added try catch blocks in my program then also not getting output.when trying to debug  it is giving output. Where should i have to add thread so that only one thread can perform  the task??

Answer (score 0):

Probably when debugging, your application had enough time to send the email.

change your code to this one:

```
Task t = Task.Run(() => {
            EnvVars envVars = EnvVars.GetSettings();
            });
t.Wait();
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct, you should not block the thread called in the OnStart hook, it will make the service stuck. OnStart should finish A.S.A.P , spawning a new thread/task to do the work.

Comment: @omerschleifer you are right, it need create a new thread. I think his problem was because the task disposed immediately before the service finished the job.  While debugging, and code hit the breakpoint the task had an enough time to processing.